# SSAS, dimension numeric value filtering

Tags: excel, filtering, ssas, pivot-table, dimension

I am using the multiple dimensional model in SSAS with a seemingly simple requirement.

I have a Product dimension table with a Price attribute. Using Excel pivot-table, I want to filter this Price attribute, for example "greater than $1000".  However the filter in the pivot table is a string only, hence I can not do perform any numerical comparison operations, but rather for equivalent strings, e.g. "$1,000.00".

My problem is similar to this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2c66fe66-a12a-4e11-9bda-1ced16abc657/row-label-filter-as-numeric), and I wonder if there is a solution/work around that I missed?

Best regards,

CT

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the thread that you link, you could create a measure for the price, and then filter that. The definition of this calculated measure would be something like

```
[Product].[Product].Properties("Price", TYPED)
```

assuming the dimension as well as the attribute are named "Product", and the attribute has the price defined as a property named "Price".

(You define a property in BIDS as a relationship from the Product attribute to the Priice attribute.)